# How to remove Horizontal spacing between the grid view in android?

Tags: android, xml, gridview

- I need to draw lines between the Grid items horizontally .
- I achieved but the problem is space between the grid items
- It is not connecting between the items instead of that it puts spacing

**GridLayout in xml file :**

```
 <GridView
    android:id="@+id/calendar_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/container"
    android:numColumns="7"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
```

**GridItem Layout :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/root_layout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/black"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_exercise"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/black"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_line"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_exercise"
        android:background="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/daytext"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/img_exercise"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_exercise_type_two"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/img_exercise"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**My code looks like :**

[image]

***I Need to join these lines .....***

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
   <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="14dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
    />
```

Comment: Where to add `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` ?

Comment: Image with text

Comment: Then go for 2nd way

Comment: i will try this :)

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
```

in your Gridview:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/calendar_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/container"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"  //add this also
    android:numColumns="7"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

Also for the lines to be connected use:

```
  <View
        android:id="@+id/view_line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  //change here
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_exercise"
        android:background="@color/color_black" />
```

Comment: i will try this :)

Comment: match parent works in view but stretch mode = "none " doesn't  works , it makes items disappears

Comment: okay then use : `columnWidth` as stretch mode,,,i have updated the answer.