# How to remove horizontal space between Gridview?

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

I'm facing a issue while using Gridview , Gridview automatically taking blank space between 2 horizontal items, even my adapter item height and width is match_parent.

i have already tried all of the answers from old question's similar of same issue but also i'm getting same error .

> the links i tried is :
>   * [GridView : Removing spaces between horizontal and vertical spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33602304/gridview-removing-spaces-between-horizontal-and-vertical-spaces)
>
> *[How to remove Horizontal spacing between the grid view in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43651088/how-to-remove-horizontal-spacing-between-the-grid-view-in-android)

**code of main xml:**

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gvCurrentMonthDayList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
    android:background="#EEEEEE"
    android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="7"
    />
```

**code of child items:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/llCalendarItem"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtCount"
    android:text="123"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/h5" />
<TextView
   android:layout_width="@dimen/common_10_dp"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:id="@+id/txtCount"
   android:background="@drawable/event_count_back"
   android:text="10"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   android:textColor="#fff"
   android:textSize="@dimen/common_5_dp"
   android:layout_height="@dimen/common_10_dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Screenshot of error :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think you have android:horizontalSpacing in your xml file.

make it zero then check for output.

Comment: change android:id="@+id/date" width to match_parent than try .this may change output

Comment: then also same result

Comment: send me your code [ without your secret code] dharmikjagodana007@gmail.com

Comment: make root element of child to frameLayout and make child width match_parent  [android:id="@+id/date"]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the value `android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"` to `android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"` or `0dp`

Comment: then also same result

Comment: What is the role of the second ```TextView``` in your **child.xml*** ?